# Invalid input syntax for type numeric due to black row value

Tags: python, sql

I posted a question a few days ago regarding "Inserting data from a CSV file to postgres using SQL", I'm trying to do it with the other form, COPY_FROM. I'm getting a similar error with what I had with the insert one, but I'm unsure how to address it:

ERROR:

```
invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
CONTEXT: COPY messages, line 1, column EXAMPLE: ""
```

CODE:

```
 with open('example.csv', 'r') as f:
            next(f)
            cur.copy_from(f, 'table', sep=',', columns=('Column1', 'Column2', 'EXAMPLE'))
            conn.commit()
```

I would imagine the issue is that they way it works, despite it being a black column valve it still has "" and therefore pasting it inside the copy_from method. Any way to remove them?

Thanks.

Comment: I think in "example.csv" file, there is a blank cell which is expected to be a numeric value. Please show an example sample from example.csv

Comment: Yes, there is a blank cell which is causing the issue but I need it to be blank for some of them. I have enabled them to be null.

Answer (score 0):

In "example.csv", there is a blank-valued cell that should be a numeric value. Possible solutions:

1- NULL out those cells. Note that NULL does not mean an empty string. use `=NA()` instead of an empty string for those columns.

2- Read all the values as "string" in your program, then convert them to numeric where the content is a member of integer.

3- Use a dummy value like `-1000` for those cells, and replace `-1000` to empty string in your program.